# cannot resolve method onPostCreate(android .os.bundle) in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer inside a `Fragment`, but i'm getting `cannot resolve method onPostCreate(android .os.bundle) in a fragment` error on the following method

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

[image]

I don't understand why.

Comment: @Onik What should I use instead? Because the navigation drawer needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why.

Because there is no such a method in [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) class. This is an `Activity`'s [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)) that should be overridden in the `Activity` class.

Comment: I have gotten the point that it is not a fragment method, does it mean I can't implement a navigation drawer in a fragment?

Comment: @crakama "does it mean I can't implement a navigation drawer in a fragment?" How are you going to use a `Fragment` inside of another `Fragment` when the drawer is hidden?. I highly recommend to stick to the official documentation concept: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: "How are you going to use a Fragment inside of another Fragment when the drawer is hidden?" I was no well informed on this until when I saw my drawer hidding and my app looking wiered. I have implemented the drawer on the my activity then inside the drawer tags I hve included the frame layout that will be replaced with a fragment...its working